# Overloading the << operator inside a class

Tags: c++, class, overloading, iostream

I usually keep my classes in 2 files : class.h and class.cpp

I want to do something like cout << myclass;

I have found examples like :

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, XXLint)
{ // do stuff
}
```

But the above function gets explicited right after the declaration.

How should I declare it in myclass.h in order to be able to use it in myclass.cpp ? And also what would the entire function's header be in the .cpp file ( eg : myclass::myclass() ).

Comment: `cout` is not an operator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's true, cout is a class and << is the operator :)

Comment: @taigitanaka, `cout` is not a class, `ofstream` is a class

Comment: `cout` is not a class, either. `cout` is the name of an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the class definition in the header:

```
struct Foo
{
  int a, b;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo&);
};
```

In an implementation (e.g. `.cpp` file):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo& f)
{
  return os << f.a << " " << f.b;
}
```

Comment: I think i've tried every possible combination but that. Why does it work without having something like myclass:: ?

Comment: @taigitanaka Because it is not a member function. `friend` means "you are a non-member function that can see my non-public stuff".